# Random absorption hearts when fighting blazes

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Around 2017, I was playing Minecraft BE with my friends. We came across a nether fortress, with a Blaze spawner. While fighting Blazes, occasionally I would receive about 6-8 hearts of Absorption by doing nothing but hitting a Blaze using my sword. They never disappeared unless I took damage. This doesn't happen anymore, and I am wondering why this happened, and when it got removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absorption hearts was actually a temporary fix for a much worse bug where blazes would deal insane damage, sometimes even killing you in one hit, even with armour and fire resistance! You can read more about it in [this](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-19535) bug track report.